# "Class Not Registered " Error comes while debugging my application 

Tags: vb.net

Hai,

i were working in Windows xp. last week I changed my OS to Windows 7.The project i have done in Vb.net(2008) . While running class not registered error comes. In another computer its works well. Why it comes.

Answer (score 1):

Is the other computer Windows 7 too?

I have personally seen "Class not registered" error for COM/DCOM (unmanaged) applications or .NET applications that expose COM Classes.

Does any of the dlls/exes on which your project depends or any dlls/exe in your project itself expose COM classes? If so, then they are not registered properly.

You can try:

a. Registering all COM classes using regsvr32.

b. Register all .NET exposed COM classes using regasm /tlb /codebase

c. Try RunAs administrator for your application.

d. Turn on Fusion logging:

> > Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
> >
> > [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Fusion]
> >
> > "ForceLog"=dword:00000001

e. Turn on DCOM Logging:

> Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Ole]
>
> "EnableDCOM"="Y"
>
> "ActivationFailureLoggingLevel"=dword:00000001
>
> "CallFailureLoggingLevel"=dword:00000001

Comment: How to  Turn on Fusion  ? and DCOM

Comment: Add the registry key that I have mentioned. Just copy the highlighted stuff to text file with extension .reg and run it.